# I can't drag gameObject into prefab public variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, inspector, prefab

I have a bullet prefab in 2D unity and I want to drag a gameObject into a public variable so I can deal damage but it won't work. Here is my code, the gameObject I want to drag in is called EnemyAI and there is a script called EnemyAI.

```
public EnemyAI EnemyHealth;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        print("Collided");
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Wall") //Change tag
            Destroy(gameObject);
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") //Change tag
            Destroy(gameObject);
            EnemyHealth.TakeDamage(10);
    }
```

I wanted it to be able to drag the game object in but it didn't let me. I have done this exact same thing before but where the enemy hurts the player, please help.

Comment: Does the game object youre trying to drop have the enemiAI component on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign an object from a scene or other file in the project to a prefab unless it is one of its children. This problem of yours has a logical root and also a logical solution. For example, if you could insert an object, if this bullet hits any enemy, it would reduce the life of the specified object, which does not seem logical. So better remove `EnemyAI` from public variable and get it from collider.

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    print("Collided");
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Wall") //Change tag
        Destroy(gameObject);
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") //Change tag
    {
        coll.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyAI>().TakeDamage(10); // it will take EnemyAI from collider that has Enemy Tag
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was being so dumb thx

Comment: @LiamParcel Thanks, in any case, if the answer helps you, give a green tick so that the answerers' efforts are not wasted.